# Сравнение даты и времени (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать сравнение даты и времени? Задача состоит в следующем, одну дату и время я задаю, например (2019-03-26T10:29) и если текущее время и дата когда-то станет больше заданного, то происходит какое то событие, например вывод в консоли...?

Comment: `Date.now() - (new Date('2019-03-26T10:29').getTime())` = разница в мс

Comment: Это я то понял, мне необходим метод componentDidMount()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, самый простой способ - это:

```
var d1 = new Date('2019-03-26T10:29'); // 10:29 
var d2 = new Date('2019-03-26T10:39');  // 10:39 разница 10 минут
var d3 = d1;

function isDifferentDates(d1, d2) {
  return d2 - d1 !== 0;
}

isDifferentDates(d1, d2) //true можешь вызывать событие
isDifferentDates(d1, d3) //false время не изменилось
```

Если хочешь внедрить этот код в React.Component, тогда используй setInterval в `componentDidMount` с интервалом 1 секунду и сравнивай любую дату с текущей, тогда ты сможешь вызывать событие.

Comment: Да я так и сделал, но спасибо за ответ, использовал setInterval в componentDidMount